# Can we control LINQ expression order with Skip(), Take() and OrderBy()

Tags: mysql, linq, linq-to-entities, devart, dotconnect

I'm using LINQ to Entities to display paged results. But I'm having issues with the combination of `Skip()`, `Take()` and `OrderBy()` calls.

Everything works fine, except that `OrderBy()` is assigned too late. It's executed after result set has been cut down by `Skip()` and `Take()`.

So each page of results has items in order. But ordering is done on a page handful of data instead of ordering of the whole set and then limiting those records with `Skip()` and `Take()`.

**How do I set precedence with these statements?**

### My example (simplified)

```
var query = ctx.EntitySet.Where(/* filter */).OrderByDescending(e => e.ChangedDate);
int total = query.Count();
var result = query.Skip(n).Take(x).ToList();
```

### One possible (but a bad) solution

One possible solution would be to apply clustered index to order by column, but this column changes frequently, which would slow database performance on inserts and updates. And I really don't want to do that.

### EDIT

I ran `ToTraceString()` on my query where we can actually see when order by is applied to the result set. Unfortunately at the end. :(

```
SELECT 
-- columns
FROM  (SELECT 
    -- columns
    FROM   (SELECT -- columns
        FROM ( SELECT 
            -- columns
            FROM table1 AS Extent1
            WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
                -- single constant column
                FROM table2 AS Extent2
                WHERE (Extent1.ID = Extent2.ID) AND (Extent2.userId = :p__linq__4)
            )
        )  AS Project2
        limit 0,10  ) AS Limit1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT 
        -- columns
        FROM table2 AS Extent3 ) AS Project3 ON Limit1.ID = Project3.ID
UNION ALL
    SELECT 
    -- columns
    FROM   (SELECT -- columns
        FROM ( SELECT 
            -- columns
            FROM table1 AS Extent4
            WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT 
                -- single constant column
                FROM table2 AS Extent5
                WHERE (Extent4.ID = Extent5.ID) AND (Extent5.userId = :p__linq__4)
            )
        )  AS Project6
        limit 0,10  ) AS Limit2
    INNER JOIN table3 AS Extent6 ON Limit2.ID = Extent6.ID) AS UnionAll1
ORDER BY UnionAll1.ChangedDate DESC, UnionAll1.ID ASC, UnionAll1.C1 ASC
```

Comment: Did DevArt fixed the Bug? I was searching for a Oracle Linq Provider. But with such a bug it's not a good option to choose.

Comment: @BitKFu: Unfortunately not. I didn't get any answer from them on this matter. My solution in the end (accepted answer) is probably even better. I would need count and records anyway. And working with IDs only is making it really fast and simple. I'd have to do something like it anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### My workaround solution

I've managed to workaround this problem. Don't get me wrong here. I haven't solved precedence issue as of yet, but I've mitigated it.

**What I did?**

This is the code I've used until I get an answer from *Devart*. If they won't be able to overcome this issue I'll have to use this code in the end.

```
// get ordered list of IDs
List<int> ids = ctx.MyEntitySet
    .Include(/* Related entity set that is needed in where clause */)
    .Where(/* filter */)
    .OrderByDescending(e => e.ChangedDate)
    .Select(e => e.Id)
    .ToList();

// get total count
int total = ids.Count;

if (total > 0)
{
    // get a single page of results
    List<MyEntity> result = ctx.MyEntitySet
        .Include(/* related entity set (as described above) */)
        .Include(/* additional entity set that's neede in end results */)
        .Where(string.Format("it.Id in {{{0}}}", string.Join(",", ids.ConvertAll(id => id.ToString()).Skip(pageSize * currentPageIndex).Take(pageSize).ToArray())))
        .OrderByDescending(e => e.ChangedOn)
        .ToList();
}
```

First of all I'm getting ordered IDs of my entities. Getting only IDs is well performant even with larger set of data. MySql query is quite simple and performs really well. In the second part I partition these IDs and use them to get actual entity instances.

Thinking of it, this should perform even better than the way I was doing it at the beginning (as described in my question), because getting total count is much much quicker due to simplified query. The second part is practically very very similar, except that my entities are returned rather by their IDs instead of partitioned using `Skip` and `Take`...

Hopefully someone may find this solution helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't worked directly with Linq to Entities, but it should have a way to hook specific stored procedures into certain locations when needed.  (Linq to SQL did.)  If so, you could turn this query into a stored procedure, doing exacly what is required, and doing it efficiently.

Comment: Yes. You can use stored procedures. Well to some extent. That's why I'm also using EF Extensions, where I can do whatever I like with stored procedures. But I would still like to solve this the EF way. It seems something common. Nothing unusual...

Comment: If it does turn out to be a bug, this or hard-coding the SQL (i.e. no LINQ at all) may be the only other efficient option.

Comment: @Randolpho: What do you mean by *hard coding SQL*? Do you mean eSQL or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from you comment the persisting the values in a List is not acceptable:

There's no way to completely minimize the iterations, as you intended (and as I would have tried too, living in hope).  Cutting the iterations down by one would be nice.  Is it possible to just get the Count once and cache/session it?  Then you could:

```
int total = ctx.EntitySet.Count;  // Hopefully you can not repeat doing this.
var result = ctx.EntitySet.Where(/* filter */).OrderBy(/* expression */).Skip(n).Take(x).ToList();
```

Hopefully you can cache the Count somehow, or avoid needing it every time.  Even if you can't, this is the best you can do.

Comment: Caching `Count` doesn't really solve the problem. If I move `OrderBy` clause to the last query (so it's combined together with `Skip` and `Take`) I get the same result. Order is applied after result has been cut to a subset. Caching count would only save me one DB call. But results would still be incorrect.

Comment: In my code, the ordering of the query operators would ensure that the skip and take work on the intended order.  I would guess then that your query is not returning results in the intended order.  Have you looked at the sql using either (**A**) `.ToTraceString()` or with (**B**) SQL Profiler (http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/sql_server_profiler.asp)?  If you run the sql straight against your db, do you get the intended ordering?

Answer (score 0):

Are you absolutely certain the ordering is off? What does the SQL look like?

Can you reorder your code as follows and post the output?

```
// Redefine your queries. 
var query = ctx.EntitySet.Where(/* filter */).OrderBy(e => e.ChangedDate); 
var skipped = query.Skip(n).Take(x);

// let's look at the SQL, shall we?
var querySQL = query.ToTraceString();
var skippedSQL = skipped.ToTraceString();

// actual execution of the queries...
int total = query.Count(); 
var result = skipped.ToList();
```

**Edit:**

> I'm absolutely certain. You can check my "edit" to see trace result of my query with skipped trace result that is imperative in this case. Count is not really important.

Yeah, I see it. Wow, that's a stumper. Might even be an outright bug. I note you're not using SQL Server... what DB are you using? Looks like it might be MySQl.

Comment: I'm absolutely certain. You can check my "edit" to see trace result of my query with `skipped` trace result that is imperative in this case. Count is not really important.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: I replied in my question. I think maybe a bug you have found. What DB are you using? MySQL? Postgres?

Comment: As stated in my tags I'm using MySql. And I'm using Devart's dotConnect. Can you try this same thing with MS SQL? So you would do all thre operations and see what happens there? Maybe it's MySql, because it has a really nice feature of `limit skip, take` syntactic sugar.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: Ahh, I missed the tag, my bad. I'll be happy to run it against SQL Server, but I'll have to get back to you on it. I suspect the issue isn't so much MySQL itself as it is the expression tree generator in dotConnect.

Comment: Please do. I'd be delighted to hear about MS SQL results. I'm using three tables. The main one has the `ID` (PK) and the `ChangedDate`, the other two have foreign keys to this `ID` in the main table. And I'm eager loading the other two tables (unreleated between eachother) while querying the main table (using `Include()`).

Answer (score 0):

Could you please create a sample illusrating the problem and send it to us (support * devart * com, subject "EF: Skip, Take, OrderBy")? 
Hope we will be able to help you. 
You can also contact us using our [forums](http://www.devart.com/forums) or [contact form](http://www.devart.com/company/contact.html).

Comment: Thank you very much. I've sent you an email.

Comment: Hello, Robert. We have replied to your mail 26.03.2010 at 08:37.
I have not received any mail server error reports.
Could you please check the issue at your side or provide us with an alternative e-mail?

Comment: Any progress regarding this issue?

Answer (score -1):

One way:

```
var query = ctx.EntitySet.Where(/* filter */).OrderBy(/* expression */).ToList();
int total = query.Count;
var result = query.Skip(n).Take(x).ToList();
```

Convert it to a List before skipping. It's not too efficient, mind you...

Comment: That's not an option, because entity set has waaaaaay too many records. That's why I'm using paging in the first place.

Comment: Yeah, I  know. It may not be efficient, but for smaller recordsets, it does work.

Comment: Well I don't have the fortune of small result sets... :(